# Android early boot console over usb

Tags: boot, kernel, logging

I'm trying to port newer kernel versions onto my Nexus S device.

Most newer kernels panic very early on in the boot process. I would like to debug this.
However, since the phone has been provided to me by my school, I cannot get a hold of a serial port (if it does exist..not sure)

Is there any way I can obtain the messages via usb onto my PC?

Comment: This sounds like a rather development-related issue. As we here are dealing with the end-user, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) might be a better place to ask this (also better chances for developer-related answers ;)

Comment: @Izzy It could be from a user perspective too. What if he just wanted a way to see the logs as soon as he turned on the PC? Could it be done via adb?

Comment: Porting a kernel is close enough to development for it to be on topic at Stack Overflow, there are people at SO who would be able to give you a lot better answers than we could, we are just trying to make sure you get the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/SamsungSerial) describes how to get access to the serial console on the Nexus S, which is really the only way of debugging boot problems. It's not for the faint-hearted, though: you need a UART-to-USB module, with resistors connected across certain pins, all connected to your phone. If you screw it up you will blow up the phone.

The same information's also [mirrored here](http://trac.osuosl.org/trac/replicant/wiki/NexusSBootloader), in case the first site should disappear.

BTW, if you'd tried asking this on Stack Overflow instead of here, you'd have found [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433150/android-early-boot-console-over-usb) which has the same link I just found :-)